# Adding and subtracting rows in a Pandas dataframe using if/else comprehension?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 2, 3], [0, 4, 1], [1, 0, 1]], index=['1', '2', '3'], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
>>> df
   A  B  C
1  0  2  3
2  0  4  1
3  1  0  1
```

I am trying to add another row to this dataframe where the new row is calculated by summing the first two rows and subtracting from the 3rd row then checking if the calculated value is positive or not using aan if/else comprehension. Below is the sample code:

```
df.loc['4'] = [0 if (df.iloc[0:2].sum()-df.iloc[[2]])<0 else df.iloc[0:2].sum()-df.iloc[[2]]]
```

However, this is returning the following error.

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I am looking to get something like this

```
  A  B  C
1  0  2  3
2  0  4  1
3  1  0  1
4  0  6  3
```

Comment: your expected output is row 4  with values `[0, 6, 3]` ?

Comment: @JoeFerndz that is correct.

Comment: note `df['4']` will create a new column not new row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `clip`:

```
s = df.iloc[:2].sum().sub(df.iloc[2]).clip(0)

df = df.append(s, ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C
0  0  2  3
1  0  4  1
2  1  0  1
3  0  6  3
```

Comment: Thanks, Quang. How can I keep the original index names?

Comment: `df.loc[4] = s`?